# How to delete rows which used to concatenate a string using MySql

Tags: mysql, group-concat

In the table `t_contents` stored an a database `MySql version 8.0.17` I have these rows

```
+--------------------------+----+
| Contents                 | ID |
+--------------------------+----+
| - Gaio Giulio Cesare     |  1 |
| - Quinto Orazio Flacco   |  2 |
| - Marco Porcio Catone    |  3 |
| • Marco Tullio Cicero    |  4 |
| • Publilio Siro          |  5 |
| • Lucrezio               |  6 |
+--------------------------+----+
```

I need concat the rows when string start for `-` or `•` symbol and using `DESC SEPARATOR "\n"` for this return (e. g. `•` symbol)

[image]

Using this query insert new `group_concat rows` in table `t_contents`

[image]

After this insert new `group_concat rows` in table `t_contents` how to do delete from table `t_contents` the single row?

```
+--------------------------+----+
| Contents                 | ID |
+--------------------------+----+
| • Marco Tullio Cicero    |  4 |
| • Publilio Siro          |  5 |
| • Lucrezio               |  6 |
+--------------------------+----+
```

Any help would greatly appreciate... Thank you.

**PS: I'm sorry but if paste codes of query the question not posted...**

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for t_contents
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_contents`;
CREATE TABLE `t_contents`  (
  `Contents` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of t_contents
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('- Gaio Giulio Cesare', 1);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('- Quinto Orazio Flacco', 2);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('- Marco Porcio Catone', 3);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('• Marco Tullio Cicero', 4);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('• Publilio Siro', 5);
INSERT INTO `t_contents` VALUES ('• Lucrezio', 6);
```

Comment: Google -> `sql group_concat tutorial`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for reply, I need delete rows which I used to concatenate a string